# Django change local datetime format

Tags: django, datetime, format, local

I have a Django app in which I use the translation system.
I want Django to print datetime objects in local format, but not in the default format in currently print for me.

Example, for english translation, I get the datetime objects in this format:
May 14, 2015, 1:26 p.m.
And I want to get this format: `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`
i.e 03/14/2015 13:26

For other langauges I still get the month name in the output in the local language (like 'May 14'), and I dont want that. For other languages I just want `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set custom format for different languages.

In settings:

```
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = [
    'mysite.formats',
    'some_app.formats',
]
```

Then create the files like this:

```
mysite/
    formats/
        __init__.py
        en/
            __init__.py
            formats.py
```

See complete ref here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files

Then in formats.py, you set it as you want. For english:

```
import datetime    

DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y h:i'
```

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.